# Python Arithmetic Sequence Sum

Tags: python, sum

How do I make a code that follows this? `1⋅2+2⋅3+3⋅4+…+(n−1)⋅n`

For example, if `n=5`, the answer is `1⋅2+2⋅3+3⋅4+4⋅5=40.`

`n` cannot be less than or equal to two or more or equal to 1000

This is my code for now but it doesn't work.

```
n = int(input())
if n>= 2 and n<=1000:
    sum = 0;
    numbers = range(1, n+1)
    for amount in numbers:
        if (amount % 2 == 1):
            sum *= amount
        else:
            sum += amount 
    print(sum)
```

Comment: `sum = 0` is a bad idea because it tramples over a builtin name (and the semi-colon is not needed)

Comment: You are complicating your life here. You should just loop on the numbers "amount" from 1 to n-1, and add  to sum the product of amount and amount + 1.

Answer (score 2):

For every number between `1` and `n-1` (inclusive), you need to multiply it by the following number, and then sum them all. The easiest way to represent this is with a comprehension expression over a `range` call:

```py
result = sum(i * (i + 1) for i in range(1, n))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reproduce exactly the scheme you give

- for each number, mulitply it with itself-1, and sum that

```
def compute(n):
    if 2 <= n <= 1000:
        total = 0
        for amount in range(1, n + 1):
            total += amount * (amount - 1)
        print(total)
```

---

But that's the same as multiplying each with itself+1, if you change the bound to get one step less

```
for amount in range(1,n):
    total += amount * (amount + 1)
```

Then you can use builtin methos `sum` and a generator syntax

```
def compute(n):
    if 2 <= n <= 1000:
        total = sum(nb * (nb + 1) for nb in range(1,n))
        print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to approach it mathematically, you can have the answer in a single expression.

Dry run your code. You will see that for n = 5, you are doing as follows:

```
Num of Iterations = 6 (1 -> 5+1)
Iteration 1
sum = 0 + 1 = 1

Iteration 2
sum = 1 * 2 = 2

Iteration 3
sum = 2 + 3 = 5

Iteration 4
sum = 5 * 4 = 20

Iteration 5 
sum = 20 + 5 = 25

Iteration 6
sum = 25 * 6 = 150
```

In this, you are completely disregarding the BODMAS/PEMDAS rule of multiplication over addition in the process of regenerating and calculating the series

What you need to do is

```
Iteration 1:
sum = 0 + 2 * 1 = 2

Iteration 2:
sum = 2 + 3 * 2 = 8

Iteration 3:
Sum = 8 + 4*3 = 20

Iteration 4:
Sum = 20 + 5*4 = 40
```

Here, We have broken the step as follows:

```
For each iteration, take the product of (n) and (n-1) and add it to the previous value
```

Also note that in the process, we are first multiplying and then adding. ( respecting BODMAS/PEMDAS rule )
So, you need to go from n = 2 to n = 5 and on each iteration you need to do (n-1)*(n)

As mentioned earlier, the loop is as follows:

```
## Checks for n if any
sum = 0
for i in range(2, n):
    sum = sum + (i-1)*i
print(sum)
```